# Is it necessary to deallocate an AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer? If so, how?

Tags: swift, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

With ARC, I can just set all of an object's strong references to `nil` to deallocate it.

With an `UnsafePointer` or `UnsafeMutablePointer`, I need to manage its memory explicitly:

```
let buffer = sizeof(Int8) * 4
var ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.alloc(buffer)
defer {
    ptr.destroy()
    ptr.dealloc(someVal)
    ptr = nil
}
```

But the documentation is ambiguous for `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` objects.  I cannot explicitly call `destroy` or `dealloc` on a `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`.

```
var ptr: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil
defer {
    ptr = nil
}

// assign something to ptr
```

The name implies that it is autoreleased after it falls out of scope, but do I need to set a `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` to `nil` in order for it to be autoreleased?

Here's an example where I use an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` to get a list of all of the classes currently loaded by the runtime.  Note that when invoking the power of the Objective-C runtime some functions require a `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` rather than just a `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

```
var numClasses: Int32 = 0
var allClasses: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass?> = nil
defer {
    allClasses = nil // is this required?
}

numClasses = objc_getClassList(nil, 0)

if numClasses > 0 {
    var ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass>.alloc(Int(numClasses))
    defer {
        ptr.destroy()
        ptr.dealloc(Int(numClasses))
        ptr = nil
    }
    allClasses = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass?>.init(ptr)
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(allClasses, numClasses)

    for i in 0 ..< numClasses {
        if let currentClass: AnyClass = allClasses[Int(i)] {
            print("\(currentClass)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the answer but I would be surprised if it wasn't handled when it fell out of scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to set it to `nil`. It is supposed to be constructed from an autoreleased pointer (assuming it was constructed correctly, it will release itself). At the same time, don't hold onto it past the current stack frame. The `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` does not keep the object alive. When the enclosing autorelease pool is popped, the wrapped object will be released and probably deallocated. Like the name says: it is *unsafe*.

Avoid problems by never creating `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` yourself in Swift (**edit**: except when it's really an UnsafeMutablePointer and the C header import has made a mistake, see below). If you're using it correctly, it should be transparent glue between Swift's `inout` and an Objective-C return-by-pointer parameter.

You generally create a `var` matching the contained type and pass it in by `inout`.

e.g. if you want to call the function:

```
func someFunction(obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>)
```

then you invoke it like this:

```
var myObject: AnyObject? = nil
someFunction(&AnyObject)
```

and everything will work out.

I'm not aware of any other situation where you should hold an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`. I don't think you should be manually constructing one at all on the Swift side except as `nil`. It is precariously difficult in Swift to construct an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` with non-`nil` contents since the only way to autorelease is using `Unmanaged`.

**Responding to your update...**

The `objc_getClassList` function signature is a glitch in Swift's automatic C importing. It incorrectly assumes that a `Class *` parameter should be imported as `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>`. You really just need an `UnsafeMutablePointer` which you can get from an array:

```
var allClasses = Array<AnyClass?>(count: Int(objc_getClassList(nil, 0)), repeatedValue: nil)
allClasses.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (inout bp: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<AnyClass?>) in
    objc_getClassList(AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer(bp.baseAddress), Int32(allClasses.count))
}
```

Comment: "Avoid problems by never typing `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` yourself in Swift."  What about in cases where you are invoking the Objective-C runtime, such as calling `objc_getClassList`?  That requires an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass?>` pointer rather than a `UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass?>`.

Comment: I've updated my question to include an example where I actually use an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`.  Maybe you can find an optimization where this type of pointer is not required.

Comment: Oh that. That's a bad header import. I've amended my answer.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks!  I think I figured out the issue.  With `Protocol * __unsafe_unretained *class_copyProtocolList(Class cls, unsigned int *outCount)` the protocol pointer is bridged as Autoreleasing.  But changing `__unsafe_unretained` to `__weak` causes the pointer to be bridged as a regular `UnsafeMutablePointer`.  Do you think this is indented behavior?  I thought `__weak` and `__unsafe_unretained` mean the same thing in an ARC environment?

Comment: `__weak` has special meaning (it gets explicitly set to `nil` when target is deallocated) whereas `__unsafe_unretained` is just a pointer and continues to point to deleted memory. Corollary: `__weak` can *never* retain the target (not even as autoreleasing), whereas `__unsafe_unretained` probably does maintain ownership but it's manual (not handled by ARC), hence the differences here. Clearly though: Apple haven't audited the objc/runtime.h header for Swift compliance -- I would assume all ownership rules in the interface are wrong and read the documentation to get ownership rules correct.

Comment: Thanks again Matt, tremendous answer.  Do you think I should file a Swift bug about the incorrect header imports?  Or a Radar?