# UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>: What's the risk?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm receiving one of these in a callback from an Objective-C library: `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`

I'm able to parse it. I'm also able to create one to send it back to the library, but: **What are the risks of working with the "unsafe" type? How do I avoid those risks?**

Also, the Objective-C library is using `uint8_t *` which bridges to Swift as this `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`... is this the best thing for Swift interop?

Comment: Can you change the ObjC library, and make it give NSData?

Comment: Related reading: https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2q1uhr/unsafe_pointers_objective_c/

Comment: Thanks @kennytm, it's more like, "can you convince the C people to change their lib." I'll probably just wrap it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UnsafeMutablePointer` is how you represent a C pointer in Swift.  It's unsafe because the underlying memory the pointer points to could change at anytime without the Swift pointer knowing.  It also has no information about the size of the memory block that it points to (thanks Martin).

If your library requires you to use C types, in this case a pointer to a `uint8_t`, then you must use `UnsafeMutablePointer`.  Otherwise I if you just want to represent an array of numbers I would wrap all of the `uint8_t` types in an `NSArray` as `NSNumber` types (or `NSData` if you are pointing to a byte stream) for easier bridging.

You can avoid these risks by dereferencing the pointer (if it is non-nil) and copying the value stored at the pointer to a variable in your Swift application.

Comment: Thank you, that WAS the question.

Comment: In my ignorance, I was basically worried that it would somehow present a leak.

Comment: It is also unsafe because the pointer has no information about the *size* of the memory block that it points to, and you can easily access invalid memory locations through the pointer.

Comment: Great points Martin.  @DanRosenstark it would only cause a leak if you `malloc` memory at the address of the pointer and don't `dealloc` or `destroy`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36186540/2415822) for related discussion (ignore the autoreleasing pointers).

Comment: @JAL sorry to belabor the point: there is no risk that I would be doing unmatched `malloc` in Swift, correct?

Comment: @DanRosenstark if the SDK you are using is just passing you a pointer, you are in the clear.

Comment: @JAL what about if I am passing to the SDK, using `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(27)` to create it?

Comment: @DanRosenstark I might need more context.  If you're calling `malloc` or `alloc` without calling `free`, that's definitely a point where a memory leak could occur.  What does this SDK do?

Comment: The SDK speaks MIDI over a wire. I still have control of the object and could call `destroy` if that's what necessary.

Comment: @DanRosenstark if you manage the memory that the pointer points to, then I would explicitly call `destroy`.  Just make sure the SDK cleans itself up before destroying the pointer.  You don't want that SDK thinking that the memory is still available after the pointer has been destroyed on the application side.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for your patience and generosity with explaining all this. Respect!

Comment: @MartinR thanks! "Access invalid memory locations" and crash, get incorrect data, or both/neither?

Comment: @DanRosenstark potentially all of the above.